# How to make the IntArrayBag generic?

Tags: java, generics, collections

This is the [IntArrayBag](https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/edu/colorado/collections/IntArrayBag.java) I'm talking about. For the sake of the question, here are the data fields and the constructor:

```
   private int[ ] data;
   private int manyItems;

   public IntArrayBag( )
   {
      final int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 10;
      manyItems = 0;
      data = new int[INITIAL_CAPACITY];
   }
```

My question is, how could I make this class generic so that this method would take any type of object as an argument (instead of an integer)? I was thinking about making the array generic but according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020527/how-to-create-generic-array) answer arrays cannot be generic and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32008752/java-generic-field-declaration) answer stating that you cannot have generic data fields.

How would one make this class generic then? Thank you!

Comment: The same way `ArrayList` does - look at [the code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk10/jdk10/jdk/file/777356696811/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/ArrayList.java).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the class generic by using `List<T>`:

```
public class ArrayBag<T> {
    private List<T> data;
    private int manyItems;
    public IntArrayBag() {
        final int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 10;
        manyItems = 0;
        data = new ArrayList<T>();
   }
}
```

This would take care of non-primitive types. Primitives would require boxing, making the class sub-optimal for use with `int`s, `long`s, etc.

Note that you would need to use `equals` in place of `==` in situations like this:

```
if (target == data[index]) ...
```

The above should be rewritten as

```
if (target.equals(data[index])) ...
```

after checking `target` for `null`.

You could also "piggyback" on `ArrayList<T>`'s ability to grow automatically, which will let you remove array growth logic from your class.

Comment: Wow is it really that easy...? I'll go test it out, thanks for the quick answer! :)

Comment: This answer is slightly misleading. The OP seems to think you can't have a field of type `T[]` and by suggesting to use `List<T>` instead it could be interpreted as confirming that.

Comment: @PaulBoddington You are right. However, I didn't want to suggest to OP to stay with generic arrays because of the headaches he'd have with them. Using `List<T>` should be the "default" solution, even though the alternative solution is definitely possible.